# máscara moeda real em array php jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho um campo para inserir um valor monetário num array mas a máscara só funciona no primeiro input, quando adiciono nova linha a máscara não funciona.

Nesta linha **$("#finTpVal").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ',** já testei com id e class do input...

O código:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.224.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mask.money.js"></script>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
   <tr>
      <td height="25" align="center" valign="middle">Tipo</td>
      <td height="25" align="center" valign="middle">Valor</td>
      <td height="25" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
      <td height="25" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="tr_clone">
      <td height="30" align="center" valign="middle">
      <select name="tipo[]" id="tipo>
      <option value="">-</option>
      <option value="1">Tipo 1</option>
      <option value="2">Tipo 2</option>    
      </select>
      </td>
      <td height="30" align="center" valign="middle">       
      <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" class="maskreal" value="">
      </td>
      <td height="30" align="center" valign="middle">
      <span class="tr_clone_add" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Adicionar">
      +</span>
      </td>
      <td height="30" align="center" valign="middle">
      <span class="tr_clone_del" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Apagar">
      -</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
(function($) {
  $(function() {
      $("#finTpVal").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', 
        showSymbol:true, 
        thousands:'.', 
        decimal:',', 
        symbolStay: true
    });      

      var table = $('#table-data');
      table.on('click','.tr_clone_add', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
          var clone   = thisRow.clone();
          clone.find('#finTpVal').val('');
          thisRow.after(clone);
          return false;
      });
      table.on('click','.tr_clone_del', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if ($('.tr_clone').length > 1) {
              var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr");
              thisRow.remove();
          }
          return false;
      });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Porque o clone não traz os bindinds dos eventos e outras coisas associadas, você precisa executar o `.maskMoney` no novo elemento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como coloquei no comentário, você precisa executar novamente o `.maskMoney` para que o elemento que foi clonado também funcione.

Veja um exemplo (usei a classe para não precisar me referir ao ID, e também coloquei as opções numa variável para evitar duplicar o código):

```
var ops = {symbol:'R$ ', 
        showSymbol:true, 
        thousands:'.', 
        decimal:',', 
        symbolStay: true
    }
$(".maskreal").maskMoney(ops);      

      var table = $('#table-data');
      table.on('click','.tr_clone_add', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
          var clone   = thisRow.clone();
          clone.find('#finTpVal').val('');
          thisRow.after(clone);

          $(".maskreal").maskMoney(ops);  
          return false;
      });
      table.on('click','.tr_clone_del', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if ($('.tr_clone').length > 1) {
              var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr");
              thisRow.remove();
          }
          return false;
      });
```

Veja aqui o exemplo funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/514868/

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa chamar novamente o método `.maskMoney`, você pode criar um método que chame esse outro método e dentro dele configurar todas as suas máscaras, e sempre que adicionar um campo novo, é só chamar `UpdateMasks` segue o código de exemplo:

```
function UpdateMasks()
{
     $("#finTpVal").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', 
         showSymbol:true, 
         thousands:'.', 
         decimal:',', 
         symbolStay: true
     });
}
```

Dentro do evento que é chamando quando `tr_clone_add` é clicado você pode chamar a função configurada `UpdateMasks`.

```
  table.on('click','.tr_clone_add', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
      var clone   = thisRow.clone();
      clone.find('#finTpVal').val('');
      thisRow.after(clone);
      UpdateMasks();//atualizando as mascaras.
      return false;
  });
```